# String.equals() method not matching "\n" character

Tags: java, newline, equals

So I have a problem with the String class's equals() method. I''m trying to find check to make sure that user input is not simply a new line character ("\n"), but whenever I compare the user input that is just a newline, it always returns false. Here is the code:

```
command = kb.nextline();
if(!command.equals("\n"))
{
    performProcess(command);
}
```

Where "kb" is the Scanner. Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of trying to guess what might be there that's not matching, why not use a debugger or logging and actually see what's there?

Comment: Meanwhile, I don't use Java very much, but the docs for [`Scanner.nextline`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) say: "This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end." So… why are you expecting it to match `"\n"` in the first place?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use this code

```
command = kb.nextline();
String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
boolean hasNewline = command.contains(newline);
if(!hasNewline)
{
    performProcess(command);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tony. That isn't exactly what I need but it lead me to an idea that worked. Instead of checking for a new line I'm just going to trim() the command then check for an empty string.

Answer (score 8):

> This method returns the rest of the current line, **excluding any line separator at the end**.

From the [relevant documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--).